# Azure B2C passwordless sign up with only email in custom Policy

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

My system needs to use passwordless with email authentication in both sign up & sign in. 
That mean user just needs to enter an email, then the system will send the one time passcode into that emai & let user sign in (if there is no account yet, just create a new one with that email silently with default information) 
I tried [this sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/passwordless-email) & it works for exist local users (with email & password) 
Is there anyway to create local user with only email? My users just see the input email screen & the input passcode screen. They don't need to fill anything else.

Answer (score 2):

When a local user account is created, the **password** property must be set, which is why [that sample flow](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/passwordless-email) prompts the new user for this.

If you don't want to prompt for this, then the **password** property can be set to a random value, as follows.

1. Remove the **newPassword** and **reenterPassword** claims as output claims from the **LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail** technical profile:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
  ...
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />

    <!-- Optional claims, to be collected from the user -->
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" />
  </OutputClaims>
  ...
</TechnicalProfile>
```

2. For the **AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail** technical profile, add an input claims transformation to that generates the new password and set the **accountEnabled** property to **false** so that the new user can't sign in with the generated password:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail">
  ...
  <InputClaimsTransformations>
    <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GenerateNewPassword" />
  </InputClaimsTransformations>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" Required="true" />
  </InputClaims>
  <PersistedClaims>
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="accountEnabled" DefaultValue="false" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" />
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" PartnerClaimType="password"/>
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="passwordPolicies" DefaultValue="DisablePasswordExpiration,DisableStrongPassword" />
    ...
  </PersistedClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

3. Declare the **accountEnabled** claim as follows:

```xml
<ClaimType Id="accountEnabled">
  <DisplayName>Account Enabled</DisplayName>
  <DataType>boolean</DataType>
</ClaimType>
```

4. Declare the **GenerateNewPassword** claims transformation of type [**CreateRandomString**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/string-transformations#createrandomstring) as follows:

```xml
<ClaimsTransformation Id="GenerateNewPassword" TransformationMethod="CreateRandomString">
  <InputParameters>
    <InputParameter Id="randomGeneratorType" DataType="string" Value="GUID" />
  </InputParameters>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and get the error after verify email `An account could not be found for the provided user ID`
The new user can't be created (I checked in AD)

Comment: Apologies @R4j You might have to also add "DisableStrongPassword" to the **passwordPolicies** property (since the generated password, as a GUID value, won't contain any uppercase letters).

Comment: Thanks, I use `<PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="passwordPolicies" DefaultValue="DisablePasswordExpiration,DisableStrongPassword" />` and get the same error, it can't create new user

Comment: Hello, could you help me with this error? Or is there anyway to debug it?

Comment: Hi @R4j. I haven't been able to reproduce the same error. You can debug a custom policy as described by this post: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-troubleshoot-custom.

Comment: Hi @R4j, just wondering if you ever solved this. I am stuck with the same error "An account could not be found for the provided user ID"

Comment: @Rafferty I contacted Azure support and they said that they didn't support for signup passwordless yet. I had to do workaround by create user (in another page) before going to b2c auth site by using Azure AD graph api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations (it's different that MS Graph API)

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the policy with a second sample https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/passwordless-email

The specific changes can be found in this commit: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/commit/af3288e585ecd7101c3f6eb6c26c09b5b1bde2eb

The newly created policies/passwordless-email/policy/TrustFrameworkExtensions_passwordless_only.xml file contains the configuration of a passwordless signup through email confirmation. It can be found here:

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/af3288e585ecd7101c3f6eb6c26c09b5b1bde2eb/policies/passwordless-email/policy/TrustFrameworkExtensions_passwordless_only.xml

Comment: Can you add here what you've updated? Or put this in a comment instead? It looks a lot like it's just a link.